# Deleting temporary file using Java runtime.exec function

Tags: java, runtime, temp

I'm stuck in a situation.

```
String tmpfolder = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
\\this is the path C:\Users\biraj\AppData\Local\Temp\ 
tmpfolder = tmpfolder.replace("\\", "\\\\"); 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c del "+tmpfolder+"IEDriver.dll /f /s /q");
```

When I run this code it does not delete the `IEDriver.dll` file. 
But when I give the static path of the temporary folder then it deletes that file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c del C:\\Users\\biraj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\IEDriver.dll /f /s /q");
```

Can anyone explain to me why the first code didn't work? What's wrong in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing literal `\` into a literal `\\` in your second line.
When we write code, we use `\\` inside a string to represent a literal `\` to the program, but your `tmpfolder` variable already has the correct literal `\` inside it.

If you **delete** the following line, it should work.

```
tmpfolder = tmpfolder.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

The easiest way to understand the difference is to just print the string you constructed, as well as the literal string and **compare them visually.**

```
System.out.println("cmd /c del "+tmpfolder+"IEDriver.dll /f /s /q");
System.out.println("cmd /c del C:\\Users\\biraj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\IEDriver.dll /f /s /q")
```

Another possible problem is that you need to change

```
"IEDriver.dll /f /s /q"
```

to

```
 "\\IEDriver.dll /f /s /q"
```

Of course the visual comparison will answer this question definitively.

Comment: i delete the second line.still its not deleted

Comment: @user1254261, Use the second half of my solution, and see if you can spot the difference. My guess is that you may be missing a `\\ ` in front of `IEDriver.dll`.

Comment: can you tell me if i could delete the folder while deleting that IEDriver.dll file as it becomes empty after deleting the file inside it.

Comment: @user1254261, See this question to learn how to delete the directory along with the file: http://superuser.com/questions/204406/whats-the-equivalent-to-rm-rf-with-windows-command

Comment: i dont have the directory name only the file name

Comment: @user1254261, Please ask a new question with details about exactly what paths you have and do not have.